# forbid her anything and it became her desire

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

Clash of Kings by George R. R. Martin

> “And Arya, well . . . Ned’s visitors would oft mistake her for a
> stableboy if they rode into the yard unannounced. Arya was a trial, it
> must be said. Half a boy and half a wolf pup. **Forbid her anything and**
> **it became her heart’s desire**.

Catelyn talks about her daughter Arya, who she thinks is long dead. She remembers how she used to behave like a boy, not a proper lady. Catelyn says that Arya desired to accomplish anything that was forbidden by her mother Catelyn.

I understand the sentence in context, but I'm confused about this structure the author used. Is this some kind of clause here? -> **Forbid ... and it became ...** . What is the tense of **forbid** here and why is it used *with* **past simple** [became]?

I never encountered such a device. Can anyone help me deal with grammatically? Would appreciate any extra resources to read up on it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I would say that “Forbid her anything“ in this context is an unusual use of the imperative construction. The verb “forbid” is in the plain form, which has multiple uses: as the bare infinitive, the so-called “present subjunctive”, the present indicative non-third-person-singular, and the imperative.

A paper that I think is relevant: [Imperatives under coordination](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328030258_Imperatives_under_coordination), Ezra Keshet and David Medeiros. Keshet and Medeiros discuss this construction, but actually seem to conclude that it is not an imperative because of its reference to a past situation. However, I’m not sure what it is in that case.

Comment: An old TV ad used to suggest: "Promise her anything, but give her Arpege."

Comment: The link you give shows clearly that this general construction was the imperative several centuries ago. It's not clear to me whether today's English speakers consider it to be the imperative, a conditional with omitted words, or just an idiom that uses the infinitive. It would be interesting to know when it started being used with the past tense in the consequence clause; was it after people stopped considering this construction to be an imperative?

Comment: But to me, it's the same beast whether it has the present tense or the past tense in the consequence clause; saying that this changes the interpretation of the verb form is hair-splitting at its finest.

Answer (score 2):

Martin is writing a conditional sentence; he is not speaking of something that has actually happened, but is a possibility. If the sentence was written with more words it would be:

> "[If you] forbid her anything, [then] it became her heart's desire."

Martin is using forbid as a **present tense conditional verb** because the sentence is conditional, but it is still a very likely possibility.

[Here is an article about conditional verbs and their proper tense](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/conditionals-verb-tense-in-if-clauses/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So do you propose that in this particular case Martin uses Present form of "forbid"? I wonder why is it not the past? Cause using "If + Present Simple + Past Simple" seems against the rules.

Comment: @artek Most dictionaries I just looked at did not include "forbid" as a past tense for "forbid"; they all listed "forbade" as the past tense. Unless there is an exception that I am unaware of, I would say that Martin using Present Simple + Past Simple is just a grammatical error on his part.

Answer (score -3):

In this sentence, forbid(verb) is used as a past tense. Forbid and forbade are the past tense of the word 'forbid'.
And, 'became' is used because the author talks about what happened in the past.

In other words, the sentence could be formed as, *"If you forbade her anything, it became her heart's desire."*

Comment: "*Forbid and forbade are the past tense of the word 'forbid'.*" No, that's not true. *Forbid* is ***not*** the past tense of *forbid*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I cross-checked it before posting the answer. [link](https://pasttenses.com/forbid-past-tense#:~:text=past%20tense%20of%20forbid%20is%20forbid%2C%20forbade%20or%20forbad.)

Comment: Or there's [this site](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-forbid.html) which does not include it. While it's fine in the sentence in the question, it's still the present tense that's being used—and fine as a general statement of fact: ***Paint*** *her red, and it became the colour she liked most.* The tenses don't need to match.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, you are correct. This might be one of those few exceptions.

Comment: @JasonBassford's example can't be changed to _Painted her red, and it became the colour she liked most_. So _forbid_ can't be the past tense here. And I don't know what you mean by "one of those few exceptions" -- exceptions to what?

Comment: Forbid is being used as a conditional in this sentence, Martin chose to drop the "if, then" portion of the sentence. Martin is not referring to an event that happened, he is referring to an event that could happen (a conditional).

Comment: In this context "forbid" functions as a general statement of truth, whether in the past, present or future.  "It became," though in the past tense, functions the same way. This is what has happened in the past, it happens in the present and it will happen in the future. Whatever grammatical terms you attach to the sentence, this is the writer's meaning.